# in my java client server program how client can send continious messages to server with out receiving a reply message from server?

Tags: java, sockets

when i send a message from client to server as hello,it is printed and showed in server side but when i send another message from client without sending any message from server the message sent from client is not showed in server until message from server is sent.... please give me a solution to solve it

server code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket s=ss.accept();
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(is);
    String str="",str2="";
    while(true)
    {
        if((str=din.readUTF())!= null)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        str2=br.readLine();
        dout.writeUTF(str2);
        dout.flush();

    }
```

client code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
    Socket s=new Socket("192.168.0.110",1234);
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(is);

    String str="",str2="";
    while(true)
    {
        str=br.readLine();
        dout.writeUTF(str);
        dout.flush();
        if((str2=din.readUTF())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(str2);
        }
    }
```

Comment: DataInputStream.readUTF() and BufferedReader.readLine() are blocking IO calls. That means they will wait until data is available or until the stream ends.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Your title says you don't want to read from the server, but your code reads from the server. Make up your mind. NB data to be read with `readUTF()` must be written with `writeUTF().`

Comment: the problem is , when i send a second message from client to server with out sending any message from server ,the server side is waiting for an input from user (br.readline).so the second message is not displayed at the server until the input message is given by the user to the server. iam not able to find the logic , so please help me with the logic